# Steam will not launch [Ubuntu 15.10]

Tags: steam

Ive been trying to run steam on Ubuntu 15.10 for hours and it just won't run. I installed it using: 
sudo apt-get install steam.
I clicked to agree to the terms and conditions and got through to the 200,000Kb update and it installed the necessary package. I clicked on steam and low and behold nothing happened

Comment: run steam in terminal `steam` [edit] your post with the output of the terminal.

Comment: SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Comment: [edit] your post with the full output of the `steam` command.

Answer (score 1):

Steam uses its own libraries, probably the error is due to the usage of a system provided library in place of steam's.

To fix that open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

```
mv $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.bak
mv $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Comment: Why would you be root to move around files in your home directory?

Comment: @muru its just in case the permissions have changed in the steam directory.